# Do ISS astronauts have to be conversant in both English and Russian?

Tags: iss, astronauts, astronaut-lifestyle, language

I've noticed that some of the American astronauts on the ISS can speak (at least a smattering of) Russian and similarly, some of the Russian cosmonauts are fluent in English. Is such bilinguality a requirement for all/some of the occupants of the ISS? If not, how do the two parties communicate?

Comment: When you find yourself in an abandoned Soyuz vessel, it helps to be able to read the manual in russian. ;-)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From the NASA [Astronaut Candidate Program](http://astronauts.nasa.gov/content/broch00.htm) brochure:

> Applicants should be aware that selection as an Graduation from the Astronaut Candidate Program will require successful completion of the following: International Space Station systems training, Extravehicular Activity skills training, Robotics skills training, **Russian language training** , and aircraft flight readiness training.

From [JAXA's website](http://www.jaxa.jp/projects/iss_human/astro/index_e.html):

> After being selected, astronaut candidates undergo Basic Training. They obtain basic knowledge and technical skills in space engineering, space science, space medicine, the Space Shuttle and ISS systems, the **English and Russian** languages. They also receive flight training and physical training. Upon completion of Basic Training, they are officially certified as astronauts …

From the Russian Cosmonaut Training Center's [Candidate Selection Criteria](http://www.gctc.ru/main.php?id=1253):

> ... знания **русского языка** (письменно и устно) должны быть не ниже хороших, относительно требований средней школы Российской Федерации; знания **английского языка** на оценку не ниже «хорошо» по требованиям вузов Российской Федерации;

Translation:

> **Russian language** skills (written and oral) must not be less than *good*, according to the requirements of high school in Russian Federation; the knowledge of the **English language** assessment at least *good* according to the requirements of higher education institutions of the Russian Federation