# Career in Planetary Science with an Engineering background

Tags: planetary-science, engineering

I am passionate in achieving a career in Planetary Science. I have a bachelor's degree in mechanical engineering background with an average academic record. I want to pursue a career in Planetary Science in Canada. What advice would you give for a person who is willing to achieve a career in planetary science with an engineering background? Is there any alternative approach like, choosing PG Diploma in Aerospace/Aeronautical Engineering and choosing masters in Planetary Science or related to that field?

Comment: The field of planetary science may undergo a large bifurcation in the near future the same way geology could be basic studies of geological processes in the Earth, or helping large mining companies find more oil, diamonds, rare earth's, etc. So keep an eye on how things are going in private space mining as well as planetary probe launches by space agencies.

Comment: [Wanted: Canadian moon rover, space mining technology](https://www.cbc.ca/news/technology/space-technology-tenders-csa-1.4837311) and [A Weird Canadian Tax Incentive Could Get Space Mining Off the Ground](https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/aeyg4e/asteroid-mining-canada-tax-incentive) and [Space Mining is in the Mix as Natural Resources Canada Makes Long Term Plans](https://spaceq.ca/space-mining-is-in-the-mix-as-natural-resources-canada-makes-long-term-plans/)

Comment: The only advice I can think of is to try very hard to follow what you enjoy doing. If you like engineering, then pursue paths that have emphasis on engineering solutions to the study of planetary science. If you like the science of planets itself, then choose paths that emphasize that. Don't see the degree as the goal, look carefully at what exactly you will learn, and to whom you will be exposed (fellow students, teachers, corporate and government sponsors). These are door-openers.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Is there any bridging courses (or) Astronomy related programs to apply to a Canadian Colleges/Universities for PG Diploma (1 year) and then carrying out my research in Planetary Science? I am deeply stumbled upon it. Kindly suggest me a way.

Comment: What is it about planetary science that attracts you?  What do you want to do within that discipline?  If you want to be part of an instrument team, your mechanical engineering background might be sufficient.  If you want to be part of the science team, then you'll most likely need to pursue some sort of physics-based graduate school type of path.  Getting in the door a the right place is just as important as the degree(s) you pursue.  Contact Canadian planetary scientists and ask them essentially the same question you asked here; most are very open to helping and giving advice.

Comment: You may want to look at my answer https://space.stackexchange.com/a/31326/26446, which explains how to become a Canadian *astronaut*, but which has some information which could help you.  The top programs in Canada are McGill and the University of Toronto, both of which offer master's degrees in aerospace engineering, with many subspecialty areas that you could choose to focus your research.  Good luck!